# Missing artifact Maven Nexus

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

Hello i am trying to get and external library from a nexus,

i Did setup my settings.xml as following:

```
<settings >
 <servers>
<server>
  <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
  <username>MyID</username>
  <password>MyMDP</password>
</server>
    <server>
  <id>nexus-releases</id>
  <username>MyID</username>
  <password>MyMDP</password>
</server>
 </servers>
</settings>
```

And my pom.xml is like this :

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <name>Releases</name>
        <url>MyHTTPURL/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshot</name>
        <url>MyHTTPURL/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

with my dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.calis.digital.cdr</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdr-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not suppose to need more to be able to connect nexus to get the library but it returns missing artifact and i have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: Correct groupId/artifactId/versions? Does the artifact exist in repository?

Comment: i checked with the url and yes it seems i have the good groupId/artifactId and the good snapshot version

Comment: What is the output during build on command line?

Comment: 09/07/2018 11:32:51 UTC+2: [WARN] The POM for com.calis.digital.cdr:cdr-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: delete the locale cache and rebuild on plain command line...